# Sending High Importance email through Outlook using Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

Using win32com.client package, I'm able to send an HTML email using outlook through Python. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mark an email "high priority" or "high importance".

Here is the code I'm using to successfully send out an email (with no priority marking):

```
RTFTEMPLATE = """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=3D"Content-Type" CONTENT=3D"text/html; =
charset=3Dus-ascii">
<META NAME=3D"Generator" CONTENT=3D"MS Exchange Server version =
08.00.0681.000">
<TITLE>%s</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->

<P DIR=3DLTR><SPAN LANG=3D"en-us"><FONT =
FACE="Times New Roman">
%s
</FONT></SPAN><SPAN =
LANG=3D"en-us"></SPAN></P>
<br>
%s
</BODY>
</HTML>"""

Format = { 'UNSPECIFIED' : 0, 'PLAIN' : 1, 'HTML' : 2, 'RTF'  : 3}
profile = "Outlook"


#session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
#session.Logon(profile)
mainMsg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mainMsg.To = "RECIPIENT"
mainMsg.Subject = subject
mainMsg.BodyFormat = Format['RTF']
mainMsg.HTMLBody = RTFTEMPLATE % (subject,html,bad_table)
mainMsg.Send()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating your message through the COM `Outlook Object Model`. This model is fully documented, which can be a great help in situations like this.

For instance, the `MailItem` you are creating is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320330.aspx). As you can tell from that page, it has a property [Importance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866759.aspx) which you can set to 2 (olImportanceHigh) to mark the message as "high importance".

In code

```
mainMsg.Importance = 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was looking for that keyword: Outlook Object Model. On a semi-related note, widows task scheduler doesn't seem to like win32com python script. Outlook will shoot out an error that reads "We coundn't start your program". If you have no clue, I'll start another question thread. Thansl Paul-Jan

EDIT: Looks like it's because Python is trying to open another instance of Outlook. At least that's the best guess I have.

Answer (score 2):

To mark a message so that it's recognized as 'high priority' by Outlook, add the following line to the message headers:

```
X-Priority: 1
```

But, I couldn't tell you how to add lines to the message headers by way the component that you are using.

Comment: Hm... this is where the problem comes up for me. I'm not too familiar with Python calling up a windows application (I wrote my code based on researching examples, not the principles), so I have no clue where to even start... Do you have any recommendations on where I can start looking into?

Comment: I'm not sure you have to call a windows application (outlook) to do what you are doing.  In other words, I don't think you have to program outlook to send the message, just because you want to send the message with the 'high priority' attribute.  You can simply send the message from python the usual way (by way of the email package), and include the line above in the message headers.  There is an example in following that link shows how to customize the message headers: http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be more robust solution. I'll have to study it when I get some time. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these additional headers;

```
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
X-MSMail-Priority: High
Importance: High
```

See e.g. http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp for code examples and discussion.